# Using Bokeh Server in Google Cloud AI Notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, jupyter-lab

I am attempting to build and test some bokeh components in the Google Cloud AI notebook environment. I have been using this cloud instance for several months with little to no issues but I cannot seem to get the tutorial, https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html, working. Has anyone successfully worked with a bokeh server in this environment?

The tutorial does not seem to work for my use case. Several JavaScript errors are returned when following and adapting this method.

```
handler = FunctionHandler(modify_doc)
app = Application(handler)
show(modify_doc, notebook_url=remote_jupyter_proxy_url)

def remote_jupyter_proxy_url(port):
    """
    Callable to configure Bokeh's show method when a proxy must be
    configured.

    If port is None we're asking about the URL
    for the origin header.
    """
    base_url = URL OF AI NOTEBOOK
    host = urllib.parse.urlparse(base_url).netloc

    # If port is None we're asking for the URL origin
    # so return the public hostname.
    if port is None:
        return host

    service_url_path = NOT A JUPYTER HUB SO UNCLEAR WHAT SHOULD BE HERE
    proxy_url_path = 'proxy/%d' % port

    user_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(base_url, service_url_path)
    full_url = urllib.parse.urljoin(user_url, proxy_url_path)
    print(full_url)
    return full_url
```

When patching together the previous code, I receive the following message when inspecting the notebook:

panellayout.js:213 Mixed Content: The page at 'URL' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'URL'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: What's the URL? Where does it come from? All of Bokeh's JS and CSS resources are available via HTTPS and have been for several years.

Comment: Honestly, in my case, I am unsure what that value should be. From the Bokeh documentation it looks like it should be the URL your notebook is operating at and in my case that is a google create and managed URL. So the variable URL in this case is the literally URL to my cloud notebook that I've edited out for privacy purposes.